# Error " 2>&1; returned with exit code: 1" during CMake configuration in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cmake

Error during CMake configuration in visual studio 2019 (Version 16.4.3)

I have created a simple CMake project from the template provided in visual studio 2019. It connects to remote Linux server and errors out while generating "Unix Makefile" with the following error.

```
cd "/home/ppatori1/.vs/CMakeProject6/a2fef020-7ae8-4d61-bea2-3b0e6b20371f/out/build/Linux-Debug";/home/omega/apps/redhat-x86_64/cmake/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/.vs/CMakeProject6/a2fef020-7ae8-4d61-bea2-3b0e6b20371f/out/install/Linux-Debug "/home/ppatori1/.vs/CMakeProject6/a2fef020-7ae8-4d61-bea2-3b0e6b20371f/src" 2>&1; returned with exit code: 1
```

I checked the remote Linux server and found that it creates a file with name "1" and when I concatenate it; the content inside the file "1" is as following

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/xyz/.vs/CMakeProject6/a2fef020-7ae8-4d61-bea2-3b0e6b20371f/out/build/Linux-Debug/2" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

When I copy-paste and try to run the same command i.e.

```
cd "/home/ppatori1/.vs/CMakeProject6/a2fef020-7ae8-4d61-bea2-3b0e6b20371f/out/build/Linux-Debug";/home/omega/apps/redhat-x86_64/cmake/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/.vs/CMakeProject6/a2fef020-7ae8-4d61-bea2-3b0e6b20371f/out/install/Linux-Debug "/home/ppatori1/.vs/CMakeProject6/a2fef020-7ae8-4d61-bea2-3b0e6b20371f/src" 2>&1;
```

directly on the remote Linux server it works fine and generated the required cache and makefile.

It seems while running the command from visual studio 2019, `2>&1` is not interpreted as it should be, i.e., redirection of stderr to stdout instead it does weird thing by trying to redirect file "2" which does not exist to "1" or something similar.

There is no way that I can prevent Visual Studio to append `2>&1` in the CMake command to generate Makefile. Visual Studio 2019 CMake configuration does not provide any control over how I need to generate the CMake, although I can extend it (Add to it) but not fully control it. Any help on this will be appreciated. Its a show stopper for me.

Comment: which Linux distribution and which shell are you currently using? I would strongly suggest to open a ticket at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com , there you would get support. In the mean time, try using the bash shell instead of whatever you are currently using.

Comment: Was there any resolution to this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing here with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS & Visual Studio 2019 16.7.7